# print yum repo configuration of a single repo using yum

Tags: redhat, yum, fedora

I'm trying to find a portable command line way to get the full configuration of a single `yum` repo -- without relying necessarily on the name/id of the repo or what file it's in.

I'd like to just have a pretty straight forward command -- but this is what I've cobbled together.

Let's use `epel` as an example, I've come up with something like: (forgive the ugly prototype)

```
$ yum repolist -v "$(yum info epel-release | 
   perl -ne 'print if s/^From repo\s*:\s//')" |
   perl -ne 'print if s/^Repo-filename\s*:\s//'
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
$
```

So, using `epel-release` as a way to identify which repo I care about and then finding the repo file associated with that repo.

How do I grab just the stanza in that repo file that is for `epel` -- no debug, no source, no other random repos appended to the file. I can imagine some beginning and ending regex magic -- starting with `[<Repo-id>]` and until I see the next `[<Next Repo-id>]` -- that's pretty easy. `/start regex/../end regex/`

Is there a better way?

Comment: Quick and dirty code would be something like ... repo=epel; sed -n "/\[$repo\]/,/^$/p" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo but that's fragile and likely to break in the face of small changes to input file. Better would be to use something like the Perl Config::IniFiles module to parse the file properly. Perhaps depends what your end goal is.

Comment: @PaulHaldane Agreed, I was playing around with something very similar to your regex -- I was hoping to find some yum utility/command that would make this just work. Perl Config::IniFiles is a good starting point for a more robust solution. Thanks